# Stl error with the new visual 2013 community

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, stl

Just trying the new visual 2013 Community Edition.
My old project does not compile with it.

```
1>  Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\iostream
1>  Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sstream
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sstream(71): error C2059: syntax error : '('
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sstream(370) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_stringbuf<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sstream(71): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sstream(370): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\sstream(12)' was matched
```

This is related to the new platform toolset (v120) when I change to the old v100 (visual 2010) everything compiles just fine.
Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code that triggers the error. Will just `#include <iostream>` trigger it? Also, show `sstream:71` +/- 10 lines.

Comment: yes, only #include <iostream>

Comment: What if you create project from scratch and compile a source that has only one line: `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: No problem with an empty project

Comment: Then check settings of your project, pay attention to preprocessor definitions, include paths, force includes and precompiled headers. Also, try to preprocess the source file you can't compile and try to compile preprocessed file, this may give you a hint. Also check VC++ Directories in Project Settings, usually those should be default values.

Comment: Thanks, I will try everything ASAP and keep you informed (this is a side project).

Comment: After some research, it's the delete redefinition from the Fluid Studio Memory Manager that causes problem. #define delete (m_setOwner  (__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__),false) ? m_setOwner("",0,"") : delete